# Feeding multiple ``.npy`` files as input into a Keras encoder-decoder model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to feed two .npy files into a encoder-decoder model in `tf.keras`. The files are big and don't fit in the memory. To load the data I'm trying the following strategy:

```
mmap_enc = np.load('encoder.npy', mmap_mode='r')
mmap_dec = np.load('decoder.npy', mmap_mode='r')
mmap_target = np.load('target.npy', mmap_mode='r')

encoder_input_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(mmap_enc ).batch(batch_size)
decoder_input_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(mmap_dec).batch(batch_size)
target_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(mmap_target).batch(batch_size)
```

Then, when I feed the `encoder_input_data`, `decoder_input_data` and `target_data` to the model

```
model.fit(
    x=[encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data],
    y=target_data)
```

I get the following error

> ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class
> 'list'> containing values of types {"<class
> 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset'>"}), <class
> 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset'>

I'm sure the model is correct because when I use a small sample of arrays, before saving and loading as `tf.data.Dataset`, the fitting works normally.

Regards,

Comment: I don't understand your strategy - you are still trying to load the whole files to memory

Comment: @Andrey, hummm, I was thinking that by loading the files in the `mmap` mode and using `tf.data.Dataset`, the whole files aren't loaded to memory. The worse part is that it's not even working and throw the error the mentioned error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't feed a list of generator. The data out of the generator must have the right shape from the start. In your case, it would be

```
((encoder_input, decoder_input), target_data)
```

You can achieve the desired structure by using `tf.data.Dataset.zip` :

```
encoder_input_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(mmap_enc )
decoder_input_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(mmap_dec)
target_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(mmap_target)
zipped_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip(((encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data), target_data)).batch(batch_size)
```

Comment: It works! Thanks you! For pedagogical matter, would like to know how you came to this answer. Did you read in a book/blog?

Comment: The Tensorflow website has a good guide on how to build data pipeline with `tf.data` : [tf.data: Build TensorFlow input pipelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data)

Comment: Let me ask you another question. In the way that I am reading the files and creating the datasets, are the whole files loaded completely to the memory or just batch-by-batch?

Comment: I have no idea how the `mmap_mode` of numpy interracts with `tf.data`.